# Something wrong with encoding of .properties or JSP

Tags: jsp, encoding, utf-8, internationalization, properties

I have jsp file:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;
charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<c:set var="language"
    value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}"
    scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="localization.text" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="${language}">
<head>
<title>JSP/JSTL i18n demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8"><select id="language"
    name="language" onchange="submit()">
    <option value="en" ${language=='en' ? 'selected' : ''}>English</option>
    <option value="ru" ${language=='ru' ? 'selected' : ''}>Russian</option>
</select></form>
<form name="loginForm" method="POST" action="controller"><input
    type="hidden" name="command" value="login" /> <label for="login"><fmt:message
    key="login.label.login" />:</label> <input type="text" name="login" value="">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="password" /> <label
    for="password"><fmt:message key="login.label.password" />:</label> <input
    type="password" name="password" value=""> <br>
<fmt:message key="login.button.submit" var="buttonValue" /> <input
    type="submit" name="submit" value="${buttonValue}"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you could get from written above the problem is in encoding and the problem is in Russian language. So here is my .properties file (text_ru.properties in localization folder):

```
login.label.login = Логин
login.label.password = Пароль
login.button.submit = Отправить
```

Btw,it's English file:

```
login.label.login = Login
login.label.password = Password
login.button.submit = Sign in
```

But browser gives me this thing:

[image: jsp pic]

I saved my .properties files in utf-8 and tried it with the help of two programms (the first is Eclipse and the second is Notepad++) and I don't really know what to do with this encoding problem.

Will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, when `.properties` files are read via a `ResourceBundle`, it is expecting ISO-8859-1 always.

The usual approach is to unicode-escape the non-ascii characters in the properties file. Then it will look something like that:

> hours.label=\u0427\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0435

[AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) is an eclipse plugin that makes the escaping and unescaping during development easy.

Another, more tedious approach is to provide your own tag that uses your own `ResourceBundle` implementation that in turn uses `.load(reader)`, where the `reader` is using `UTF-8`