# Netbeans not supporting unicode

Tags: netbeans, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to convert my desktop application(made using swing) in bengali using the properties file or resource bundle.But when I paste the bengali character in the properties file it is showing boxes.

I have tried the following things:-

1. I have change the Font to MS Aerial Unicode.
2. I have also made changes in netbeas config file present in the dir "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.1\etc"
   **-J-Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1**
3. I have also tried to change the encoding to UTF-8 from project properties.
4. In my project xml file the encoding type is ISO-8859-1, So I have also tried to change the encording of project to ISO-8859-1.

The application has hindi properties file as well which is working fine.

Please find below mentioned link for the Image of the issue netbeans.

[Image Link for the same issue](http://i904.photobucket.com/albums/ac248/rakeshsinghal18/UnicodeProblemNetbeans.png)

Thanks in advance. Please provide the solution ASAP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something wrong with encoding of .properties or JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423025/something-wrong-with-encoding-of-properties-or-jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the font to the MS Aerial Unicode worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've been unable to get these characters to display within code in Netbeans.  ✰☆★☞☛❸➂❤♡✉  My project is set as UTF8.  Even "Courier New" didn't work for me, even though it does in Notepad++ with these same characters. I still haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: I've finally formally asked this as a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644558/netbeans-not-displaying-utf8-unicode-characters-emoticons-correctly