# How to render Ethiopian amharic character in netbeans windows 10

Tags: netbeans

I have a problem on writing and printing out amharic character in netbeans ide, when I try to print out on the system the netbeans ide doesn't display them correctly instead it displays boxs, any one can help me pls? 
The language code is 'am' and country is ET (ETHIOPIA).THANK YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans needs a font that supports Amharic in its editor window and **Output** window. I tried a few of the widely used fonts in NetBeans but (surprisingly) they all rendered Amharic characters as empty rectangles, so I found one that explicitly supports Amharic: [Abyssinica SIL](https://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/)

I downloaded that font as an EXE file (use the ZIP file for Linux) and ran it to install the font in Windows. Then I restarted NetBeans and changed its default font to **Abyssinica SIL**:

- Select **Options** from the **Tools** menu and click the **Fonts & Colors** icon.
- On the **Syntax** tab click the ellipsis (...) button to the right of the **Font** field and choose the **Abyssinica SIL** font you just installed, and click **OK**.
- The NetBeans editor will use that font immediately, and correctly display Amharic text in the editor window.

However, Amharic text in the **Output** window will still be rendered as empty rectangles. To fix that:

- Download [the ZIP file](https://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/) for Abyssinica SIL.
- In the NetBeans **Ouput** window right click and select **Settings...** from the popup menu to open the **Options** window, click the **Miscellaneous** icon, and then click the **Output** tab.
- Click the **Import...** button, click the **Browse...** button and choose the ZIP file you just downloaded: **AbyssinicaSIL-1.500.zip**. When you click **OK** to close the **Select Options to import** window you'll get a scary warning "*Import may irreversibly overwrite your current settings...*" but click **Yes** to continue. NetBeans will restart.
- After the restart go back to the **Options** window where you imported the ZIP file, click the **Miscellaneous** icon, and then click the **Output** tab. Click the ellipsis (...) button to the right of the **Font** field and choose the **Abyssinica SIL** font you just installed and click **OK**. Amharic text will now render correctly in the **Output** window.

Here's a simple program and its output to show it works :

[image: NetBeansAmharicText]

Notes:

- There's no need to specify country or language to resolve this. However, running the app from the **Command Prompt** window still renders Amharic as empty rectangles, and the font cannot be changed to **Abyssinica SIL**. I suspect the solution for that may involve setting the locale appropriately in Windows.
- **Abyssinica SIL** is not a mono-spaced font so only set it as the NetBeans font if you need to enter Amharic text in the NetBeans editor. (I'm sure there are mono-spaced fonts that support Amharic - I just grabbed the first one I found.)
- I also tried running the app in Eclipse and Intellij IDEA without any configuration changes. In both cases the Amharic text rendered correctly in the editor. The output also rendered correctly in Eclipse, but as empty rectangles in Intellij IDEA. If you use Amharic text heavily you may want to consider switching to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans preference(setting) change the font from its default to Nyala. after that the boxes will be changed to Amharic texts.
hope your problem is solved