# Unable to Insert Unicode Characters on File Titles

Tags: unicode, character

I'm experiencing the same problem reported with these characters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644558/netbeans-not-displaying-utf8-unicode-characters-emoticons-correctly)

But in my case, this is occurring in the system itself of Windows 10, so that solution does not fit in my case. I can no longer insert those characters into file titles, just in text editors, something that was extremely easy on Windows 10 until a few days ago.

Comment: [1] You need to provide more details. As it stands your question is too vague. [2] I can't reproduce your problem on Windows 10. For example, I just created a directory named `abcdef`, and a file within the directory named `heart.txt` in Windows File Explorer with no problems. [3] You don't specify how you are trying to name the file, but if you are having problems creating a file with special characters in its name from a program you must show your code. [4] Unless there is a programming aspect to your problem it is probably off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is happening directly in explorer.exe. Not all the characters in the link present problems. [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/missing-unicode-star-after-update-to-2018-october) the last update of Windows 10 is the great suspicion. I discovered that the character discussed there does not exist in the standard Windows font (Segoe UI), but in its analogue (Segoe UI Symbol). Redirecting the font of system or creating another does not solve. W10 apparently will not recognize the 2605 Unicode position, regardless of which font is used.

Comment: [1] Strange - I just created a file named **✰☆★☞☛❸➂❤♡✉.txt** and a directory named **✰☆★☞☛❸➂❤♡✉** using Windows File Explorer on Windows 10, so all of the characters in that linked question work for me. [2] Could you update your post to clarify the specific characters that give you a problem? [3] FYI, I am running _Windows 10 Pro version 1803 OS Build 17134.472_.  [4] The link in your comment does not work.

Comment: After finding a [Microsoft link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/missing-unicode-star-after-update-to-2018-october/aa912568-6893-4788-9ce0-7f85c28df51e) it looks like this issue can arise with Win 10 version 1809. Is that what you are running?

Comment: Yes, @skomisa, I use the 1809 update. The problematic characters are ✰ ☆ ★ ➂, but there must be others. Strange that I remember doing the automatic update for 1809 and the characters were normal. The problem started from a clean installation. Unfortunate, I have numerous shared files using stars and other characters for quotation from clients.

Comment: OK. I'm upgrading Win 10 right now to verify that 1809 is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by version 1809 of Windows 10.

I successfully created a directory and a text file with names using all of the special characters in your link under Windows 10 version 1803:

[image: Release 1803]

After upgrading to Windows 10 version 1809 the file names were no longer rendered correctly in Windows File Explorer, and creating new files also had the same problem with rendering certain characters within their names:

[image: Release 1809]

The good news is that the file names are still stored correctly within Windows version 1809; the problem is purely with the rendering of the file names. If I copy one of the incorrectly rendered file names and paste it here it renders correctly:

✰☆★☞☛❸➂❤♡✉_VERSION1809

You are not the only person with this problem. For example, see [problem with Wind10 version 1809 folder naming](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/124315-problem-wind10-version-1809-folder-naming.html). If you need a fix for this you should take it up with Microsoft.

[Arguably this question is off topic for Stack Overflow, even though you linked to an on topic SO question. However, since a full explanation of your problem would not fit in the comments I posted an answer anyway.]

Comment: Talking to Microsoft, they did not give me much hope that they care about it, so I came back here where I can be sure that if I do not get a solution, it's because it does not exist ... yet. Therefore, I will positivize your effort in giving a more complete view of the matter. Now, I have to decide if I rename 893 files with equivalent characters () via Charmap until the MS decides to ban them as well, or if I switch to another OS :(

Comment: Yes, if it's a practical workaround, the best short term solution might be to rename the file names containing special characters. Exclude or replace those characters which do not render correctly in File Explorer with version 1809 of Windows 10. Unfortunately it looks like a bug which Microsoft will have to fix.

Comment: I have no hope that this will be fixed, on the contrary, it will get worse. With Windows 10, Microsoft has invested in its own library of emojis (accessible via Win+Period), and removing funcionalities of fonts may be a new way to keep control, in the knowed US tradition of making money by any means. No need for that, emoji is more easily accessible. MS could keep both functions and be kind to its customers.

Comment: I hope you are wrong - breaking the rendering of emojis in file names seems too important for Microsoft to ignore. See [Missing Unicode Star after update to 2018 October](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/missing-unicode-star-after-update-to-2018-october/aa912568-6893-4788-9ce0-7f85c28df51e). I encourage you to pursue this on SuperUser which has a [windows-10-v1809](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1809) tag for issues relating to version 1809.

Comment: It looks like I do not have enough reputation to reference my question with this tag, but as soon as I have it I will. Many thanks and happy new year, @skomisa, it's always time.